# Labelling / symbolizing layers using QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, labeling, legend, expression

I'm realizing the same analysis on specific layers on QGIS.
I need to display a specific information (like showing code "xxx", then "yyy", then "zzz" etc.) and export maps.
To make it faster and to avoid using "Themes" or generate another legend every time, I'm using another layer, with lists loaded from the contents of my first layer (xxx, yyy, zzz, etc.).
I can choose in this list what I want to see on the map and change easily.

But I can have many choices.
For "plants" I want to be able to show fields like: "codes", "correspondences", "stage" or "Layer".

For now, I'm using this kind of expression:

```
CASE 
WHEN Attribute(Get_feature('OPTIONS','id',1),'Compart') = 0 THEN
    CASE 
    WHEN Attribute(Get_feature('OPTIONS','id',1),'SL_strate') is NULL THEN
        100
    ELSE
        CASE 
        WHEN left("strate",1) = Attribute(Get_feature('OPTIONS','id',1),'SL_strate') THEN
            100
        ELSE
            0
        END
    END
WHEN Attribute(Get_feature('OPTIONS','id',1),'Compart') = 3 THEN
    CASE 
    WHEN Attribute(Get_feature('OPTIONS','id',1),'SL_Codes') is NULL THEN
        CASE 
        WHEN Attribute(Get_feature('OPTIONS','id',1),'SL_strate') is NULL THEN
            100
        ELSE
            CASE
            WHEN left("strate",1) = Attribute(Get_feature('OPTIONS','id',1),'SL_strate') THEN
                100
            ELSE
                0
            END
        END 
    ELSE
        CASE
        WHEN "Code_esp" = Attribute(Get_feature('OPTIONS','id',1),'SL_Codes') THEN
            CASE
            WHEN Attribute(Get_feature('OPTIONS','id',1),'SL_strate') is NULL THEN
                100
            ELSE
                CASE
                WHEN left("strate",1) = Attribute(Get_feature('OPTIONS','id',1),'SL_strate') THEN
                    100
                ELSE
                    0
                END
            END     
        ELSE
            0
        END
    END
END
```

And I need to do the same for labels.

Here are my questions:

- Is there a way to make shorter expressions ? Like using variables depending on the value of a field (in the layer 'OPTIONS').
- Using expressions in Opacity to control the visibility of entities is a good idea ?
- I noticed the "Rule-based" expression slower the project way more than working with opacity, colors and shapes. But is there a better solution ?

Slowly I'm adding more conditions and I don't like the way I'm always obliged to double the size of the expression to include everything.